# Making number pairs with for loop

Tags: python, list, python-zip

I've been trying to get a desired result for the past few hours without success. I get lots of negative values printed out and I'm not sure if it's because of syntax or if I don't assign my variables properly.

I'm trying to get a set of two numbers that form a time period (the first representing the timestamp of the start of a clip and the second the end of the clip).

At first, I simply added 15 seconds before each list3 items for the first timestamp and 5 seconds after for the end of the timestamp making 20 seconds clips for each items in the list. Quickly enough I realized that some of those clips are overlapping. I'm trying to insert conditions so that this doesn't happen. If a clip is to overlap, then make it longer and ignore the next item's first timestamp (start of the next clip) and so on.

I have some code, but it renders mostly wrong numbers (undesired numbers, that is).

```
list3: [3, 20, 51, 76, 106, 126, 128, 129, 163, 181, 183, 185, 187, 236, 256, 273, 277, 281, 321, 322, 323, 325, 326]

for previous, current in zip(list3, list3[1:]):
    if current > 15:
        first_current = current-15
        second_current = current+5
        first_previous = previous-15
        second_previous = previous+5
        if second_previous+15 < first_current:
            print(f"{first_current}-{second_current}")
        else:
            print(f"{first_current-second_previous}-{second_current}")
```

```
**Desired output**:
    
    if previous_second + 20 < current_first
    print current_first - 15
    
    else if previous_second + 20 >= current_first
    print (current_first - previous_second) + 5


EDIT: Desired output:
3 --> would be ignored since it is not above 15
20 --> 5-25
51 --> 36-56
76 --> 61-81
106 --> would normally be 91-111 but would be transformed (since the next item, 126, equals 111) into 126+5... so --> 91-131
```

Comment: can you post an expected output? I dont understand your question

Comment: Not clear. Please show us some examples of time stamps. Give me an example what happens to first item in your list `list3`. What do you want to do with that `3` and `20` so we can understand better. Give me your first two-three items in desired output.

Comment: So you want clips to start 15 seconds before each of the number in list3 and be 20 seconds long. If they overlap what do you want to do? Let the 20 seconds finish and move the start of the next clip to 5 second after the current ones end? Potentially stacked shifting overlapping clips this way to the end? Or move the start of the next one to exactly this ones end? This part is not clear to me from your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think you're trying to say.  It's like you have a list of events, and you have a recording that spans the entire interval.  You want to extract a set of subsets of that recording, without having a bunch of dead time, but ensuring that you have covered at least 15 units before and 5 units after each event.  Is that it?

If so, this does it:

```
list3 = [3, 20, 51, 76, 106, 126, 128, 129, 163, 181, 183, 185, 187, 236, 256, 273, 277, 281, 321, 322, 323, 325, 326]

intervals = []

for p in list3:
    # Is this point included in the current interval?  If so, 
    # extend the interval.
    base = max(0,p-15)
    if intervals and intervals[-1][0] <= base <= intervals[-1][1]:
        intervals[-1][1] = p+5
    else:
        intervals.append( [base,p+5] )

print(intervals)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 25], [36, 56], [61, 81], [91, 134], [148, 192], [221, 286], [306, 331]]
```

Comment: I just realized there's a small bug.  If the SECOND element is less than 15, it will be handled incorrectly.  I'll post a fix.

Comment: it won't be necessary, I've just put an if p > 15 condition so less than will be ignored. Thank you very much! I appreciate it a bunch.